# Jquery UI sortable drag up and down action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to determine if its being dragged up or down? how do i try to take {:action => "P"} if dragging up and {:action => "D"} when dragging down?

Comment: did you check the answer?

Comment: yes i did. i still am lost with it. it says dragged up even though i drag down. Also deep in the code of my current project i found data-action: "P" and "D", i want to call those actions when doing up or down.

Comment: Did you check run my snippet? I double checked it and I don't see any problem there. every time I drag it down it says "dragged down" and same for up. Or you are talking about your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`stop` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) of the jquery-ui's [draggable object](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable) in order to check the current position of the element vs. the original position (before the drag).

Here is an example:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    stop: function(ev, ui) {
      if (ui.originalPosition.top - ui.offset.top < 0) {
        console.log('Dragged Down');
      } else {
        console.log('Dragged Up');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable { width: 55px; height: 55px; padding: 0.5em; font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>
```